# Heroku not reflecting Salesforce Country/State picklist values, how to refresh Heroku?

Tags: heroku, salesforce, picklist, countries

We converted country/states in Salesforce to the standard picklist. Heroku doesn't seem to reflect those changes as we get loads of errors in Heroku like the one below when Heroku syncs with SF. I re-polled the account object in Heroku to refresh the account table but still the same errors. The country/state picklists are considered meta data in Salesforce in case that helps to understand the issue. Does anyone know what needs to be done in Heroku in order to get the updated list of countries/states that is now in Salesforce?

> "AccountsTrigger: execution of AfterUpdate caused by:
> System.DmlException: Update failed. First exception on row 2 with id
> 0033X00003solkfQAA; first error: FIELD_INTEGRITY_EXCEPTION, There's a
> problem with this state, even though it may appear correct. Please
> select a state from the list of valid states.: Mailing State/Province:
> [MailingState] Class.AccountHandler.HandleAfter: line 154, column 1
> Trigger.AccountsTrigger: line 17, column 1"

Answer (score 0):

You might have more luck on dedicated salesforce.stackexchange.com site. It's hard to say, sounds like error thrown from a trigger handler but you didn't post any code. Would be also good to know what do you have, [the Heroku Connect product](https://www.heroku.com/connect) or some custom integration that happens to be deployed on Heroku?

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/compound_fields_address.htm what are you mapping in your integration. Account.BillingCountry or Account.BillingCountryCode?

Worst case you could try contacting support